# Want to refactor the code to take in unknown parameters.

Tags: python, file, parameters, split, refactoring

I would like to refactor this code to take in unknown parameters. What I mean is that right now it looks through a a list of URLS (ex: http://www.blahblah.com/something/somethingelse?a=8&b=2&c=3). The code is splitting upon the query(?) and then splitting again upon the ampersand(&). After it splits, the part that is split (i.e: a=b) is put into an appropriately named file (`a_file.txt`). The thing is, what if my program runs into an unknown parameter that is not in the hash list? The information would be lost, I presume. So my question is whether Python has functions that can, A. build a brand new file that was not in the hash list before and name it appropriately and B. put the information into a file such as (`char_file.txt`). So, if there is an unknown character, make a file for it and append the information into it. Any help is appreciated.

```
import urlparse
def parse_file(input_file):
    tags = {tag: tag + '_file.txt' for tag in {'blog',
        'p','attachment_id','lang',
        'portfolio','page_id','comments_popup',
        'iframe','width','height'}}
    with open(input_file) as input:
        for line in input:
            parsed_url = urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlparse(line).query)
            if parsed_url > 0:
                for key, value in parsed_url:
                    if key in tags:
                        with open(tags[key], 'a') as output_file:
                            output_file.write(value)
                    else:
                        print key + " not in tags."
             else:
                 print(line + " does not yield query.")

parse_file()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have that `tags` variable? Just do the same thing you're doing currently, but leave the whole `tags` thing out, and it should work like a charm. Opening a file in `"a"`-mode creates it, if it doesn't exist yet.

Replace

```
for key, value in parsed_url:
    if key in tags:
        with open(tags[key], 'a') as output_file:
            output_file.write(value)
    else:
        print key + " not in tags."
```

with

```
for key, value in parsed_url:
    with open(key+"_file.txt", 'a') as output_file:
        output_file.write(value)
```

Then, you can of course also remove the `tags` declaration at the top

Comment: btw, I apologize in advance, I am new to programming.

Comment: like this: `import urlparse
def parse_file(input_file):
  with open(input_file) as input:
    for line in input:
        parsed_url = urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlparse(line).query)
        if parsed_url > 0:
          for key, value in parsed_url:
            with open(key+"_file.txt", 'a') as output_file:
              output_file.write(value)
        else:
            print(line + " does not yield query.")
parse_file()`